# Adding view with angularJS to site without angularJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I have an existing website which has a single page, without using AngularJS

And I want one of the pages that are loaded through AJAX, to be built In AngularJS

How to do it?

This is home page:

```
<body ng-app="App">
<div>
    <div>
        <div id="bodyPageDiv">
            this is home page

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="gotopage2();" />
<script>
    function gotopage2() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/page2",
            success: function (html) {
                $("#bodyPageDiv").html(html);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/app/appAngular.js"></script>
```

The page that loads from Ajax:

```
<div ng-controller="alarmController">
    <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="tag in alarms" t="parent" data-isarchived="{{tag.IsArchived}}" data-red="{{tag.IsActive}}">
                <td class="alignCenter">
                    <img src="{{tag.User.UserImageURI}}" />
                </td>
                <td class="textAlign">
                    <a href="{{tag.linkHref}}" rel="external">{{tag.User.holderName}}</a>
                </td>
                <td class="textAlign">
                    <a href="{{tag.linkHref}}" rel="external">{{tag.AlarmAddress}}</a>
                </td>
                <td class="textAlign">
                    <a href="{{tag.linkHref}}" rel="external">{{tag.User.holderPphone}}</a>
                </td>
                <td class="textAlign">
                    <a href="{{tag.linkHref}}" rel="external">{{tag.User.holderRemarks}}</a>
                </td>
                <td class="textAlign">
                    <a href="{{tag.linkHref}}" rel="external">{{tag.stringAlarmTime}}</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

result:
[image: When this page is loaded in AJAX]

Comment: inside your success block, what do you get if you put a console.log(html)..?

Comment: You make an Ajax request using jQuery's `$.ajax()`. Do you load jQuery library? Implement an error callback to check where your ajax request goes after is complete (on success or on error). Do you get any angular errors in the console?

Comment: See: [AngularJS Routing And Views Tutorial With Example](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-routing-and-views-tutorial-with-example/)